# kind of discontinuity

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you help me with this question?

What kind of discontinuity i have at the point $x=0$, if the function defined as bellow:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{x} &x<0 \\ 
 x^{2}& x\geq 0
\end{matrix}\right.$

I thought that the function has a discontinuity of the second kind at the point $x=0$, because
at least one of the one-sided limits is infinite:

$\lim_{x \to 0^{-} }\frac{1}{x}=- \infty  $

Why is it a wrong answer?

Thanks!

Comment: http://planetmath.org/Discontinuous.html says you're right. But I only know of discontinuities of first and second kind (removable and essential). Maybe your teacher is using some unusual definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an infinite discontinuity (essential discontinuity)

Since $L_- = - \infty \ne 0 = L_+$ 
So at least one of the limits are undefined ($\infty$)

**note:** For me, this is the third type, the first 2 being a removable discontinuity (by continuous extension, so where left and right limit are equal) and jump discontinuity (where it goes from eg. 3 to 9, both not undefined).
However I prefer to use the terms over the 'number'